# Confusion on statistical testing and confidence intervals

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I am currently self-studying basic statistical testing (Z-testing and t-testing of at least approximately normally distributed *one sample*) and calculating confidence interval estimates for true population means. I've seen different approaches and formulas/notations and I just want to clarify/check my understanding.

I understand that the t-test should be used when the population standard deviation is unknown or when sample size $n<30$. Otherwise the Z-test can be used with reasonable accuracy due CLT or due SD simply being known.

**Question 1:** Regardless of the chosen test, is the formula used to calculate the Z or t-score *always* of form
$$\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\text{ or } \dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$$
where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, $\mu$ the hypothesis mean, $\sigma$ the known *population* SD in the case of Z-test and $s$ the calculated *sample* SD from
$$s=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}}$$
or must I *always* use the right hand side formula? Is it never possible to simply use only $\sigma$ in the denominator if it is known?

**Question 2:** Is the formula for the confidence interval *always* of the form
$$\bar{X}\pm z^*\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}} \text{ or }\bar{X}\pm t^*\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}},$$
depending on which distribution is appropriate?

Comment: (1) If $\sigma$ is known, why would you want to estimate. (2) Formulas given are appropriate for _normal_ data. // Statement "I understand that the t-test should be used when the population standard deviation is unknown or when sample size n<30. " is a vast oversimplification. Strictly speaking, t procedures are _only_ for normal data.. They may be reasonable approximations for nearly normal data. However, for example if data are exponential, Weibull, or Pareto, then $n=30$ is often _nowhere near large enough_ to use t tests or t confidence intervals.

Comment: @BruceET Yes, I should've specified that all data is at least approximately normal as of yet. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Please edit this clarification into your Question. Not everyone reads comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the fact that $s$ is an **estimator**.  In other words, it is a function of the sample that attempts to "guess" the true value of $\sigma$.  But if $\sigma$ is known, then it doesn't need to be estimated, and the resulting test statistic using $\sigma$ will have more power.  The confidence interval will also be smaller for the same nominal coverage probability.

Note that you never use the margin of error $$z^* \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}.$$  This is wrong.  Either it is $$z^* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$ or $$t^* \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$ depending on whether $\sigma$ is known.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.